# Content-Range working in Safari but not in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, audio-streaming, http-content-range

I'm streaming audio files from a Node.js Express server with `Content-Range` headers plus no caching headers. This works ok in latest Safari instead, but it does not in Chrome.

While when streaming the full audio file with `HTTP 200`, my headers were

```
{ 'Content-Length': 4724126,
  'Content-Type': 'audio/mpeg',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, GET, OPTIONS',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'POST, GET, OPTIONS',
  Expires: 0,
  Pragma: 'no-cache',
  'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate' }
```

and it works on both Chrome and Safari `<audio>` tag.

When streaming partial contents with **HTTP 206** the headers were

```
{ 'Content-Length': 4724126,
  'Content-Type': 'audio/mpeg',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, GET, OPTIONS',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'POST, GET, OPTIONS',
  Expires: 0,
  Pragma: 'no-cache',
  'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate',
  'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes',
  'Content-Range': 'bytes 120515-240260/4724126' }
```

This led to an error of the **Chrome** page where the `<audio>` or `<video>` tag was.

Even the embedded media tag created by Chrome when using the streaming url right in the browser it is not working, and led to this

[image]

The audio file is served reading a local file and creating a file read stream via Node.js the `createReadStream` api:

```
var file = fs.createReadStream(path, {start: range[0], end: range[1]});
```

I have posted the code for the server [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53226595/streaming-audio-in-node-js-with-content-range).

**[UPDATE]**

It turns not that Chrome is more strict about `Range` and `Content-Range` requests/responses. So any `Content-Range` response must have a `Range` previous request. The typical case is scrubbing a player bar to the second S. The api will send a `"Range"` request, the server will respond with a "Content-Range" header. In my case I was sending a `Content-Range` response over an ordinary request without `"Range"`. Safari works because is more `street-html` complaint i.e. it does not strictly require a `"Range"` request before a `"Content-Range"` response. So, I removed the "Content-Range" header from my response, and not it works.
End of the story (!).

To follow up this issue I have posted in Chromium net-dev forum too in [Chrome bad Range header: Range: bytes=0-](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!mydiscussions/net-dev/hYiP5m0K7ZE)

Comment: Any reason on why you are doing the back-end with NodeJS ? what about relying on say NGINX to do the heavy lifting for you ?
By the way what player did you use?

Comment: @OAH I'm using the default HTML5 player in the browser in most of cases. Other players I have tested it are: BBC Peak.js (https://waveform.prototyping.bbc.co.uk/), WaveSurfer.js (https://wavesurfer-js.org/). I prefer to handle this within node.js because I have to modify the handle / modify the response bytes as well of the audio (like changing sampling, etc.), so I recalculate the range based on the request type in node.

Comment: aha, i see now.